# LAUNCHXL2-RM57L: Lwip is not working with GCC compiler and IAR compiler

Tags: arm, iar, texas-instruments, lwip

I am using RM57Lx LaunchPad Development Kit. I am implementing Lwip for my project with the help of this link: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/HALCoGen_Ethernet_Driver_and_lwIP_Integration_Demonstration.

It is completely worked with TI compiler on CCS and assigns IP address properly.

But if I use GCC in CCS or I use IAR compiler(Generated EMAC code for IAR using HALCOGen) and it shows an error in initializing Hardware and not assign the IP address.

And error looks like:

> ```
> =========================================
>
> Texas Instruments
> Little Endian device
> Initializing ethernet (DHCP)
> DEBUG - Getting PHY ID...SUCCESS
> DEBUG - Getting PHY Alive Status...SUCCESS
> DEBUG - Getting PHY Link Status...SUCCESS
> DEBUG - Setting up Link...SUCCESS
> ..DONE
>
>
> -------- ERROR INITIALIZING HARDWARE --------
>
> =========================================
>
> Also note that :
>
> For IAR complier there is linking error of this 4 functions _enable_FIQ(), _enable_IRQ(), _disable_IRQ(), _get_CPSR() 
> which is written in lwip_main.c,in may case i commented this 4 function for now.
> ```

Please help or guide me to solve out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Keyur Joshi

Comment: *ERROR INITIALIZING HARDWARE* - What's the tool that outputs this message? Is there any resource describing this message in any more details. Lastly, is hardware connected correctly?

Comment: This output is from IAR Embedded Workbench. This can be working fine with TI compiler using CCS. Yes, Hardware is connected properly. I used code from this link : http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/HALCoGen_Ethernet_Driver_and_lwIP_Integration_Demonstration.

Comment: And no more details besides the three words of error? How do you know hardware is connected properly? Do any other projects work (is this issue even related to lwip)?

Comment: It is working with Code composer studio(TI Compiler) and Not working with IAR Embedded Workbench(IAR compiler). With CCS These logs are print on terminal:
Initializing ethernet (DHCP)
        DEBUG - Getting PHY ID SUCCESS
        DEBUG - Getting PHY Alive Status SUCCESS
        DEBUG - Getting PHY Link Status SUCCESS
        DEBUG - Setting up Link SUCCESS
Device IP Address: 192.168.1.3 and WIth IAR logs are mention in the main problem description.  There is no error in the compilation and linking with IAR These errors are shown while executing on board it can't assign the IP address.